# Cannot connect to database in Vue data tables

Tags: php, html, sql, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify data in my php script and it works fine previously and now every page showing that error as `Your search for "{{ search }}" found no results`.

Seems this problem comes as when it cannot fetch data from the database. Here is my database class.

```
class Database
{
    public $id;
    public $user;
    public $user_name;
    public $password;

    public static function db()
    {

      $host = 'localhost';
      $dbName = 'newdata';
      $userName = "root";
      $password = "";


        $db = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbName";

        try {
            $pdo = new PDO($db, $userName, $password);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw new PDOException($e->getMessage());
        }
        return $pdo;
    }

}
```

This username and password works fine and I can connect to sql in my remote server using that password as well.

Here is some of the code which results above error.

```
<v-app>
                  <v-card>

                    <div class="row card-body">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <div class="row col-sm-12">

                        <div class=" col-sm-3">
                          <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">TO</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                              <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm" v-model="endDate">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"  v-on:click="getReport(ts)"style="margin-top:-5px">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                    <v-card-title>
                      <b>Balance Report</b>
                      </details>
                      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                      <v-text-field
                        append-icon="search"
                        label="Search"
                        single-line
                        hide-details
                        v-model="search"
                      ></v-text-field>
                    </v-card-title>
                    <v-data-table
                      :headers="headers"
                      :items="Report"
                      :search="search"
                    >
                      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
                      
                        <td>{{ props.item.col1 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ props.item.col2}}</td>
                        <td>{{ props.item.col3}}</td>
                        <td>{{ props.item.col4}}</td>
                        <td>{{ props.item.col5}}</td>
                      </template>
                      <v-alert slot="no-results" :value="true" color="error" icon="warning">
                        Your search for "{{ search }}" found no results.
                      </v-alert>
                    </v-data-table>
                  </v-card>
                </v-app>
```

Can anyone suggest where it has stucked?
Sorry for not attaching the whole php code here since It worked for many days and it sudddenly didnt worked.

Here is my vue class.

```
var UsageReport = new Vue({
  el:'#UsageReport',
  data(){
    return{
      Report:[],
      search: '',
      headers: [
                    { text: 'value1', value: 'col1 ' },
        { text: 'value2', value: 'col2 ' },
        { text: 'value3', value: 'col3 ' },
        { text: 'value4', value: 'col4 ' },
        { text: 'value5', value: 'col5 ' },
      ],
      variabl1:'',
      variabl2:'',
      variabl3:'',
      variabl4:''

    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You've bound your value (of v-alert) to true.

<v-alert .... :value="**true**" color="error" icon="warning">

This should be replaced by a variable that you set to "true" if nothing is returned by your XHR call for example.

For example, if "Report" is an array of objects that you set after your call to the backend, then you could use the following instead:

```
              <v-alert slot="no-results" :value="Report.length == 0" color="error" icon="warning">
                Your search for "{{ search }}" found no results.
              </v-alert>
```

Notice how the value of v-alert is bound to the length of the variable named Report. Which is an array in your component. If we fill it with data (see below), it should no longer show you the mssage.

```
var UsageReport = new Vue({
  el:'#UsageReport',
  data(){
    return{
      Report:['sample item1','sample item2'],
      search: '',
      headers: [
                    { text: 'value1', value: 'col1 ' },
        { text: 'value2', value: 'col2 ' },
        { text: 'value3', value: 'col3 ' },
        { text: 'value4', value: 'col4 ' },
        { text: 'value5', value: 'col5 ' },
      ],
      variabl1:'',
      variabl2:'',
      variabl3:'',
      variabl4:''

    }
  },
```

Comment: I have added my vue class as well. Can you show me what to include?

Comment: Of course you don't show how you are making a call to your backend. The GET call for example to your backend which might return the data.

Comment: I am not getting any results now, only showing the error

Comment: Where in your code are you making the request ? Are you using fetch() or AJAX ?